# Send output audio to a specific program

Tags: windows, audio

I have a concept where I would need to send the audio to a specific program.  Kind of like an output device one would choose in the control panel of windows.  The program would then send the audio out to a physical output device.  I'm not familiar with the windows environment and how I would handle such tasks, but once I got the data flowing to the right place, I can handle it.

Basically this is me asking where should I start to try to send audio output to a program?

Comment: How do you send audio to program that does not do anything with audio at all? Do you want audio capture program to take data from some virtual input (e.g. another program output)?

Comment: I am sorry. But you can't just send audio to another process. That is impossible. The only thing you can do is to create a virtual microphone device (with your own driver) and stream to that microphone. The other process can use that virtual device and use the audio data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows alone, you cannot inject audio into the recording stream of another application.  You can only monitor the audio output of another application.

To achieve what you want, you need to utilize an audio loopback driver.  There are [several to choose from](https://superuser.com/q/356536/48624).  [VB-Audio Virtual Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) is available free as donation-ware (and there is also an ASIO version).  The software you want to send audio to needs to be configured to use this "device".

Alternatively depending on your requirements, you can use [JACK Audio](http://jackaudio.org/jack_on_windows) to hook together multiple programs easily.  On Windows, JACK works as an ASIO device.  If you have software that can interface with ASIO, you can hook all of your programs together with JACK.